# mongoose aggregate returns object promise

Tags: mongoose, aggregation-framework

This query is returning an object Promise. How do I get the value of the aggregate query?
I would expect [ { maxEmpId: 26} ] but got [ { maxEmpId: '[object Promise]1' } ]

This code is right out of the mongoose model aggregate doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html

```
Emp.aggregate([
            { $group: { _id: null, maxEmpId: { $max: '$emp_id' }}},
            { $project: { _id: 0, maxEmpId: 1 }}
        ]).
        then(function (maxEmployee) {
            console.log(maxEmployee); // [ { maxEmpId: '[object Promise]1' } ]
        });
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Not sure what’s the issue, the code you provided shows that it console.log what you expect

Comment: I fixed the comment in the code. It's not returning what I expect

Comment: Looks like the value `[object Promise]1` got inserted into the database. Try `Emp.find({ emp_id: '[object Promise]1' })`. I suspect you forgot to `await` when you try to set the result + 1

Comment: You are correct! Not all of the values in the db were numeric, thus causing the bad result. Thank you. I deleted the bad documents and reran - and - it worked